# .htaccess is randomly breaking redirects

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I moved my site from domain.pl to domain.pl/blog/ and domain.pl/sklep/ to domain.pl.
I created redirects 301 in .htaccess (code below), at the begining everything seems fine, and all redirects are working, but after few minutes/hours, some of the redirects are broken. They just don't redirect and I don't know how to make them work. They are working again for few moments when I just wait few seconds and Ctrl+F5 or reupload .htaccess and they are working instantly for few moments.

The redirect domain.pl/sklep/ to domain.pl seems easy, I used 1 code line:

`Redirect 301 /sklep https://slowianskibestiariusz.pl/`

But actually problematic is domain.pl to domain.pl/blog/ redirect, where I have to make redirects for all links from sitemap.

Example:

```
Redirect 301 /bogowie https://slowianskibestiariusz.pl/blog/bogowie/
Redirect 301 /bogowie/page/2 https://slowianskibestiariusz.pl/blog/bogowie/page/2/
Redirect 301 /bogowie/page/3 https://slowianskibestiariusz.pl/blog/bogowie/page/3/
```

First redirect is working randomly, but next one are fine all the time, I don't know where to look for solution.

On this server are installed PrestaShop and WordPress.
It's Litespeed server on PHP 7.2. WWW error logs aren't sending nothing special. I'm using Notepad ++ to edit .htaccess with UTF-8 (without BOM) encoding.

This is few lines of my .htaccess:

```
# END Wordfence WAF

#sklep
Redirect 301 /sklep https://slowianskibestiariusz.pl/

#blog
Redirect 301 /bogowie https://slowianskibestiariusz.pl/blog/bogowie/
Redirect 301 /bogowie/page/2 https://slowianskibestiariusz.pl/blog/bogowie/page/2/
Redirect 301 /bogowie/page/3 https://slowianskibestiariusz.pl/blog/bogowie/page/3/
Redirect 301 /bogowie/jarowit-pan-wojny-milosci https://slowianskibestiariusz.pl/blog/bogowie/jarowit-jarylo/
Redirect 301 /en https://slowianskibestiariusz.pl/blog/en/
```

I expect to make stable redirects for articles from domain.pl to domain.pl/blog/.

Comment: First I would download the htaccess file when it starts acting up and see if it's not been modified

Comment: The problem was order of htaccess commands. CMS was overwriting my code.